# Delete saved usernames/passwords in SQL Server Management Studio's “Connect to Server” Screen when SqlStudio.bin does not exists?

Tags: ssms

I want to delete the saved usernames and passwords displayed in the "Connect to Server" screen.
In the internet (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230159/how-to-delete-server-entries-in-sql-server-management-studios-connect-to-serve)) I've read that I should delete the file `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin`, but inside of `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\` I can't find a folder `100` (only `90`and `110`). And if I start a search, I also can't find the file `SqlStudio.bin` in one of these other two folders.

I'm using Windows 7 and version 11.0.1750.32 of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the remembered login and password list in SQL Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349668/removing-the-remembered-login-and-password-list-in-sql-management-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When digging further into this I found the file at:

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin`

Comment: Thanks, now I was able to find the file! But an update of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to version 11.0.2100.60 also provides you the possibility to delete usernames/passwords by pressing `Delete` when they're selected in the DropDown-Box.

Answer (score 6):

The "100" part of the path is dependent on the version of SQL Studio:

```
 90 = v9  = SQL Server 2005
100 = v10 = SQL Server 2008
110 = v11 = SQL Server 2012
```

Since you have v11 installed (SQL Server 2012) the file will be found here:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\**110**\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such file. All I can see inside the folder `Shell` is the file `RegSrvr.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version added this but now you can expand the drop-down,  hover over the item you want to remove, and with it highlighted while the drop-down is still expanded, press the Delete key. The drop-down list will redraw immediately and remove the selection.