# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I have installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and when I try to update model from database under EDMX file I am facing that error.

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc
>   version 11.0.0.0

I  have tried to install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16978) but no joy.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

**Problem:** (Sql server 2014) This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0` not found by visual studio.

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295 and download:

- `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X64 OS or
- `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.

PS: You may need install `DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi` or `DB2OLEDBV5_x86.msi` too.

---

**Problem:** (Sql server 2012) This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0` not found by visual studio.

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580 and download:

- `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X64 OS or
- `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.

---

**Problem:** (Sql server 2008) This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 10.0.0.0` not found by visual studio.

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26728 and download:

- `1033\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X64 OS or
- `1033\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X86 OS,

(In most cases downloading this is better http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409)

then install it, and restart visual studio.

---

**Problem:** I recently got similar problem after installing *SharedManagementObjects*. assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=12.0.0.0` not found by visual studio. The problem was **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio** was not installed yet.

**Solution:**  for Visual Studio 2013 just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 and download:

- `vcredist_x64.exe` for X64 OS or
- `vcredist_x86.exe` for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.

PS: You can find *Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 20XX* for other versions of Visual Studio easily by googling it.

Comment: Thanks @Iman, I just recently came across this issue, and i have no clue how i got this issue, since everything was working normal, previously, and your solution here, solved my issue. Thanks again.!!

Comment: In my situation (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (x64); VS2013; no SQL Server installed) "ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi" had to be installed before "ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi".

Comment: @Imam I have installed sql server 2008 r2 express.. it gives me the error with the code version 11.0.0, like I have installed sql server 2012. If I try to install 1033\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi, the error doesn't change. If I try to install ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi it gives obviously error. Why? What can I do ?

Comment: @PieroAlberto: **v11** is **Sql server 2012**. What is your VS version? if VS2012 or VS2013 , when you install VS it install a light version of sql server 2012 and I think your connection string is using it instead of sql server express so you get **v11** error. typo: my name is Iman ;)

Comment: Hey @Iman. I have VS2013 and my MSSQL v.2014 so why it requires v.11 NOT v.12 ??

Comment: @SuhrobSamiev Had you checked your connection string?

Comment: For what it's worth, I had the issue after uninstalling SQL Server 2012 and installing SQL Server 2014 after VS 2013 was installed. I needed to re-install the SQL Server 2012 shared management objects for VS2013 to work properly. Installing the 2014 shared management objects had no effect.

Comment: Hi,  I have the same issue. I have done same thing as you mention in our solution but did not work in VS 2015. When I installed VS 2103 works fine. @ImanMahmoudinasab

Comment: For some others fail at the first try. I use SQL 2008 R2 express and should install Problem: (Sql server 2012) to resolve the problem.

Comment: Even if you are on a 64-bit OS, you will need the 32-bit version if "Prefer 32-bit" is checked on your app properties, which it is by default for Visual Studio  2015 console apps.

Comment: An FYI to this solution, CLR Types is a requirement to install Shared Management Objects.  You will need to download the appropriate x86/x64 CLR type install first and then install the Shared Management Objects after.

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab Sql server 2016: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Comment: @ShahriarGholami Thanks for your comment. I'll add it to my answer so other people can find it easier.

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0 not found. In order to work for me i followed your solution but i also had to install sqlServer2014 Express

Answer (score 13):

Just want to share my experience on this.

I, too, encountered this error. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 and I have an MS SQL Server 2008, though I have had MS SQL Server 2012 Installed before.

I was banging my head on this error for a day. I tried installing SharedManagementObject, SQLSysClrTypes and Native Client, but it didn't work. Why? Well I finally figured that I was installing 2008 or 2012 version of the said files, while I'm using Visual Studio 2013!! My idea is since it is a database issue, the version of the files should be the same with the MS SQL Server installed on the laptop, but apparently, I should have installed the 2013 version because the error is from the Visual Studio and not from the SQL Server.

Comment: I was having an issue w Visual Studio 2013 connecting to SQL Server 2014, and I continually overlooked the SQL 2012 SP1 link above, thinking it did not apply. Thanks to you @Gel, I did finally install the 2012 SP1 and solve this issue.

Comment: @Gel so, which SharedManagementObject have you installed?

Comment: @Piero I installed the SharedManagementObject in the package of the Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2014... I also needed the 2012 SP1 SharedManagementObject file.  Thanks for the save: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580

Answer (score 10):

I am running VS 2012, and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2, Developer Edition. I ended up having to install items from the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack. I think that the [install instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065#) noted that these items work for SQL Server 2005 through 2012. I don't know what the exact requirements are to fix this error, but I installed the three items, and the error stopped appearing.

Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack Items

- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects : [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239658&clcid=0x409) , [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239659&clcid=0x409)
- Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 : [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409) , [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409)
- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client : [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239647&clcid=0x409) , [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409)

Based on threads elsewhere, you may not end up needing the last item or two. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 & SQL Server 2014. I got the below error `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0` not found by visual studio.

I was actually expecting `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0` error because I am using SQL Server 2014.

To fix the issue, I had to install SQL Server 2012's `SharedManagementObject.msi` from the below site.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580

**Note:** You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246011/1030460 answer but focus on the error version to select the download instead of focusing on SQL Server version.

Answer (score 7):

For SQL Server 2014:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42295

Select SharedManagementObjects.msi for your architectur

Answer (score 6):

For those who are running into a slight variation of this problem, I just found a solution.

Pre-requisites:
using VS 2015 and SQL Server 2012.

Symptom: 
can't load this subsystem:
Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0

At this point you might be like me and confused that you are using SQL Server 2012 but VS 2015 is trying to use version 12.0.0.0, which comes from SQL Server 2014.
It turns out that when you install SQL Server 2012, it installs a couple of components from SQL Server 2014. At one point I removed all traces of SQL Server from my machine (using the Add Programs control panel). When I re-installed SQL Server 2012, it either didn't re-install the 2014 components or I deleted them again thinking I missed them the first time around.

The result was that I didn't have the necessary 2014 libraries on my system. I also tried to install the 2014 Shared Management Objects as pointed out above, but that didn't work because I didn't have the CLR runtime from 2014. So in order to get a VS 2015 system working with a SQL Server 2012, you have to make sure that these two 2014 packages are installed:

- ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

from [SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42295). Pick the 32 bit versions if you  need to.

[Here is the site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0f34edc8-3358-4fc9-9800-9f32a3b672e9/cant-connect-sql-server-2012-express-with-visual-studio-2015?forum=sqlexpress) that helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Just use MS Web platform Installer 4.5 to install all stuff for MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

And don't forget to reload machine.

:)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded "Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" and "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects" from @ImanMahmoudinasab mentioned link, but Shared Management Objects had problem while installing and it showed some dependencies message and at the end installation Failed!

Finally I solved the problem with Power Shell. I run PS as administrator with the below command:

```
Start-Process <path>\SharedManagementObjects.msi
```

Answer (score 1):

for version 11 download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=43339

- ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

for version 12 download the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP2 Feature Pack
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

- ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 & SQL Server 2014. I got the below error Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0 not found by visual studio.
I have tried all the things like installing

- ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X64 OS or
- ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X86 OS
- ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- Reinstalling Sql Server 2014

> What actually solved my problem is to repair the visual studio 2013(or
>   any other version you are using) now the problem is removed . What i think it is
>   problem of Visual Studio not Sql Server as i was able to access and
>   use the Sql Server tool.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using `Visual Studio 2013` with `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016` trying to **update database** with `Entity Framework migrations`

The fix was to install `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 SP1` as Visual Studio 2013 was missing the necessary libraries to connect to the SQL Server database.

Comment: Please avoid linking to off-site resources. As it might be an answer right now, the off site resource might change in the futur and won't be helpful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Supplement to Iman Mahmoudinasab's answer**

**For SQL Server 2016**, this is where to find the files:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Note that the files are in the list but you may need to scroll down to see/select it.

**From SQL Server 2017 onwards**, things change:

"Beginning with SQL Server 2017 SMO is distributed as the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects NuGet package to allow users to develop applications with SMO."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017