# Cannot find a dll for SQL Server from VS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Microsoft Visual Studio

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I cannot "see" the referenced DLL even though it is in the proper spot. I can therefore not bind the datasource to the control. What might I be failing to do?

Comment: Would you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)

Answer (score 3):

Please see original question and answer here: [`Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246011/1997229)

---

<strike>**Problem:** This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0` not found by visual studio 2012.(Sql server 2012)</strike>

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580 and download:

- `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X64 OS or
- `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.

---

**Problem:** This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 10.0.0.0` not found by visual studio 2010.(Sql server 2008)

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26728 and download:

- `1033\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X64 OS or
- `1033\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for X86 OS,

(In most cases downloading this is better http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409)

then install it, and restart visual studio.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2016 which is not listed there but the version of the file is 11.0.0.0. Unfortunately there is no SharedManagementObjects.msi for SQL Server 2016 and the one for 2012 also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From here:-

> From the error message, we can see there is some missing component in
>   VS 2012 installation. The assembly in question -
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Manangement.Sdk.Sfc version 11 - is a component
>   DLL for SMO assemblies (even though SFC was originally created for
>   more ambitious SSMS extension), and it is included in SQL Server 2012
>   Shared Management Objects.
>
> [SQL 2012 Shared Management Objects]  has dependency on [SQL System
>   CLR types] component, so you have to install SQL Server System CLR
>   Types first.
>
> [SQL Server 2012 System CLR Types] can be found in the middle of SQL
>   2012 Feature Pack web page (
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065 )

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience on this.

I, too, encountered this error. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 and I have an MS SQL Server 2008, though I have had MS SQL Server 2012 Installed before.

I was banging my head on this error for a day. I tried installing SharedManagementObject, SQLSysClrTypes and Native Client, but it didn't work. Why? Well I finally figured that I was installing 2008 or 2012 version of the said files, while I'm using Visual Studio 2013!! My idea is since it is a database issue, the version of the files should be the same with the MS SQL Server installed on the laptop, but apparently, I should have installed the 2013 version because the error is from the Visual Studio and not from the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing SQL Server Express 2014.  Apparently 2012 points to some files that are in 2014 and I completely erased all old versions of SQL Server.  After much frustration I ended up reloading Visual Studio 2013 and it set up all of the files it needed and now works with SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: Reinstalling is some last resort, but not really an answer