# Visual Studio Unable to Add Data Connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Im trying to add my local SQL Server database to Visual Studio so I can grab the connection string from it but I am getting this error message:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the Test succeeds but when I try to add I receive error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that you need to have SDK.sfc 11.0.0.0 installed.  I only had 10.0.0.0 installed.

You can use the link here to download "Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" and "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects"

[Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)

I think these are normally installed with VS 2012 but in either case it fixed the issue.  You can check your version in the assembly path:
C:\windows\assembly
[image]

The install does not require a restart but you will need to close and reopen your Visual Studio.

Comment: fine, now it would be best to accept at least one answer as the correct one; then the question is no longer unanswered. :)

Comment: This issue has direct link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing some updates from Microsoft: [one link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43d7267f-bc42-4540-9c85-e29a67691784/unable-to-add-data-connection-to-sql-server)

You could search with google/bing/whatever and find a lot of hints to get this working!

Comment: Thanks I figured it out a few minutes ago, you must have been writing your message while i was writing mine

Answer (score 0):

for both type (32 bit or 64 bit )
Open URL `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580`
Download `ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi`
Download `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi`
Install `ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi` 
Install `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi`
Restart your Visual Studio and now Everything will work smooth.
This fix was for the error (version 11.0.0.0)