# unable to create data model in visual studio 2013 in entity data model wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am unable to create data model in visual studio 2013 in entity data model wizard.after successfully selecting database,if i click on "OK" button,i am getting error like mentioned below.please help me it looks very weird to me.

Error :-

```
could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.managementsdk.sfc,version=11.0.0.0,culture=neutral,
publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
the system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when some assembly files are missing. Please see a similar problem and solution here [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1/19246011#19246011)