# Get error "could not load file or assembly microsoft.sqserver..." in ASP.NET SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I'm trying to add my `.MDF` file (DB) to my ASP.NET project. I connect the .mdf in my project to my external `.mdf` file.

Everything is ok until I want to see the tables, and then I get this error:

[enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/jbhmc5uc3/)

I have SQL Server 2014 Express, and I'm using VS 2013.

Thank you

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was just missing some installation of One program (DTsearch)  that were using at the project . it was installed in the computer where the Project built.