# Data base connection error on "microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014

I started a project (winforms c#) in my PC with VS 2010 and SQL server 2008 on win 7 and every thing works fine there.

However, today I choose to use my laptop to continue my project, where I'm using  VS 2012 ultimate and SQL Server 2014 on win 8.1. My problem is that I couldn't establish connection to Sql Server via VS.

It keeps telling me that `microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc` version 11 needed.
[image]

I located to `c:\windows\assembly` folder and found I have both ver 10 and 12, not 11.

[image]

I installed and used both `shared management objects x64.msi` and `DB2OLEDBV5x64.msi` and `SSDT` but nothing changes !

What is the problem and how can I resolve this?

Is there any way to change the machine easily with out getting stuck in this connection error ?

Comment: similar issue?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Comment: @Mahya its sql 2014 and i got this error,i tried that solution and no luck !