# LocalDb creation problems (Service based database)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, localdb

Can not create a service based database. When trying to add one into the project this appears

[image]

Been googleing for the last 4 hours without solution. I tried:

- Running VS 2013 with administrator rights
- Downloaded localDb instalation files for SQL management studio 2014
- Repairing SQL management studio
- Checking availability of a server from configuration management (SQL server service is empty by the way, not sure why)

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL Server instance in the visual studio tools -> connect to database? Have you checked that the service of sqlserver is started?

Comment: As I mentioned before, configuration management -> SQL server service is empty. I used SQL database provided by my college for the final project and it was fine. I just cant seem to create a local db.

Comment: Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh212961(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Tried adding LocalDb from Feature selection tab in the SQL server setup, but sadly there is no LocalDB there :?

Comment: Launch on a command prompt the command 'services.msc', this will open the form that you can use to manage the Windows services. In this list you may find something like 'SQL Server'. If you find it,can you write the full name of the service?

Comment: SQL Server VSS Writer,
SQL Server Browser

Comment: The localdb database instance seems missing. I don't know. Look at Microsoft website and try to download a new installation package. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx

Comment: Downloaded LocalDb installation package, installed it, ran a localdb instance from cmd, localdb info says its running, but I can't see it on the managment studio installation-> Features window. Also I can not see the service in the services.msc

Comment: Thank you for all the help bdn02. I managed to create service based database in my project and I can connect to it (on the server explorer it is showing connection icon near database). But whenever I try to add the table, I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/F35ADDs.png

Comment: Also this then trying to create a dataSet http://i.imgur.com/6zmHZHu.png

Comment: Look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1