# Getting error when trying to create Entity Data Model from existing table in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to create a data model off of an existing database table using Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2015 for an MVC application.  I'm able to test the connection to the MS SQL database I've been using successfully and choose the database itself, but whenever I click 'finish' I get error shown below.

I've tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1), but it has not worked and I can't find any other answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain you have added the assembly [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll/) to your project. You can search for this assembly and install it via NuGet, or run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  [Chase's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812435/chase) answer was close, but mine was a different version.  I'm using SQL server 2012 and, according to the error message, I needed version 12.  I found it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO.2014/).