# Visual Studio 2015 Community with MS SQLServer 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015, database-connection

Is there anybody having successfully connecting VS2015 to SQLServer 2008 (original, not R2) Express? the SQLServer seems to be running fine (connection using Management studio is okay) but I could not get connected to it using VS15. The error says something about the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0` assembly

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1) provides a nice solution to some cases but it does not seem to work in mine. If I understand correctly, the VS15 assumes the use of `SharedManagementObject` assembly 12.0.0.0 for Sqlserver 2014. But I'm running 2008 version and this package certainly cannot be installed.

Anybody knows a workaround for it?

**== UPDATED according to my answer ==**

So what if I deploy my application, which uses Entity Framework (for which I need to connect VS to SQLServer), on a machine that does not run VS2015, nor some items from the feature pack?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio 2015 or Team Foundation Server 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was stupid. And it turns out, indeed, to be the problem of visual studio 2015 always assuming the assembly for SQLServer2014. I ended up installing 2 items from the SQL server 2014 feature pack including:

- System CLR Types, which is the prerequisites for
- Management Objects

And restart the Visual Studio (it would not work without this damn critical step).