# SQL 2016 & visual studio - unable to add dataconnection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm getting the infamous "unable to add data connection". I have followed the logic in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1), but I simply cannot find the right files.

I'm using MS visual studio 2015 community, and installed SQL server with the 2016 CTP2 installation center, while the link helps to those who use MSVS 2015 with SQL 2014 server.

My error message specifies "microsoft sql server management sdk version 12".
when following the above link, i got "missing 2014 components" message, which is obvious since I'm using 2016 server... 
And I know I'm not supposed to ask here specific files, but I couldn't find the 
right one.
 If anyone could direct me to the correct file(s) link, OR ANY CORRECT SOLUTION, It would be much appreceated.

 I see from the comments that my situation is unclear: I am using the SQL server 2016, and do not wish to revert back to older versions. I am currently looking for a way to update its "shared components" version to 12.
 Many Thanks.

Comment: Given that the error message is that you are "missing 2014 components" it sounds like you need to install SQL 2104 not SQL 2016

Comment: As it is, the question doesn't make much sense. You mention an *old* CTP version, link to an EF-related question even though your question doesn't mention EF anywhere. You mention SQL Server 2016 but the error is about 2014. What EF version are you using? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to create an EF Database-First model?