# Connection to SQL Server when I add "LINQ to SQL classes"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am writing Accountancy project in C# (using Visual Studio 2015) but when I add "LINQ to SQL classes", I cannot connect to SQL Server 2008.

After creating connection in "Add Connection", when I "Test Connection", it is ok, but then I have a problem and the connection is not made.

This is the error message:

> Unable To Add Data Connection; could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.sqlserver.mangement.sdk.sfc,version=12. 0.0.0
>   Culture=neutral,publickeyToken=88845dcd8080cc91' or one
>   of it is dependencies.the system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem it has assembly not found issue and for this you need to add Shared Management Objects.

For more information refer below link

[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)