# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=myKey' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, .net-assembly

After running an ASP.NET C# application with SQL SERVER version 2012, I get the following error message:

**An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\psla\Reports\PD Listing Report - Per ED.rdlc' is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

What could be the cause? I have tried searching the net and there are references to version=11.0.0.0 but there are no references to version=12.0.0.0 for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'. Reviewing the reference Manager for visual studio 2015, I was only able to find up to version=11.0.0.0.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET TRUSTWORTHY ON? Check up this.

Comment: Any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1 12.x.x.x is SQL 2014, 11.x.x.x. is 2012  http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.au/

Answer (score 4):

In your Package Manager download the 12 version from Nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

Also see that entry for this is backward compatible in web.config

In your references folder right click and set copy local = true

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some library in your project is referencing Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0 but .NET runtime cannot find it at execution.

On the web server, where the application is running, make sure that there exists a following directory: `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\`

Also make sure that this directory has the file `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` of version 12 (12.0.2000.8). Different versions of the file can be downloaded from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/