# VB.NET Unhandled Exeptioin while opening Reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

My VB.net application throws error while opening report viewer.

Windows Version: Windows 11
Reportviewer version 2012
Sqlclrtype 2012
Visual Basic Power packs 10.0

[image]

See full error message below

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

***** Exception Text *****
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.WriteVariantOrPersistable(Object obj)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateHashForCachedDataSets()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Byte[] definition, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at d71fp?'wW\]gum2uXGxFdl(ne!.⁯⁭⁮⁫⁭‏⁯⁪⁭⁬⁯⁯⁯‍‏​​‎‍⁪‌​‎⁮⁫‏‍⁭⁭⁪()
   at d71fp?'wW\]gum2uXGxFdl(ne!.⁮‎‌⁪⁪‎⁯⁫‍‏⁪⁮⁯⁫‌‌⁮⁯⁪‌⁬‎(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Assembly information:

```
***** Loaded Assemblies *****
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4470.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
VgkcaXAHdploAFgYdCdwgsjXfkdLA
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.29
    CodeBase: file:///C:/wogapp22/ACE_Money_Pro.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4470.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4400.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4395.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4341.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
MetroFramework
    Assembly Version: 1.4.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.4.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/wogapp22/MetroFramework.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.30214.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/wogapp22/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Entity
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.Entity/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Entity.dll
----------------------------------------
MetroFramework.Fonts
    Assembly Version: 1.4.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.4.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/wogapp22/MetroFramework.Fonts.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4435.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3452.0 ((SQL11_SP1_QFE-CU).140703-1546 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4161.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2402.15
    CodeBase: file:///C:/wogapp22/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: "The definition of the report '' is invalid." suggests to me that the report needs a name that is not an empty string, but that's only a guess. Can you [edit] your question to add the relevant code where the exception is thrown?

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0" is the problem.  You provided the assembly, but it is the wrong version.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275829/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-12-0-0-0-cu

Comment: my installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version in nuget manager is 14.0.1016.290

Comment: I have updated my question with assembly information with the error