# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I am using VS 2013 and SQL SERVER 2014 and I am trying to use entity framework to connect to the DB from VS 2013. I am getting test connection succeeded when adding the Entity data model but getting the above error.

**Error** :Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0'
System cannot find the file specified

I tried so many solution, I re-installed SQLSysClrTypes.msi, 
SharedManagementObjects.msi, DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi and vcredist_x64.exe to resolve this ; but it did n't works.

Could any one please suggest me solution?

Thanks,
Saloni

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1 ?

Comment: I have re-installed this, but this didn't resolved my problem. I restarted my machine as well, but not succeeded.

Comment: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version 11 is bound to SQL Server 2012 though, but you said you have SQL server 2014. So, I wonder about this mismatch.

Comment: yes, I am using VS 2013 and SQL Server 2014, but still I am getting this issue. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Not much other than the reference I sent you earlier. My only suggestion is just install the right Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version 11's [SharedManagementObjects.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)

Comment: Alright Thanks. I will try to install this as well for SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Comment: This works for me. I had to install "SharedManagementObjects.msi" for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP1 Feature Pack, earlier I was installing this for SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to stamp as the answer, let me rewrite in the answer block from my comments.
Install the right Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version 11's SharedManagementObjects.msi from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580, because it seems like the entity is using the previous SQL Server (2012).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** (Sql server 2012) This issue happens when assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0 not found by visual studio.

**Solution:** just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580 and download:

ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X64 OS or

ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.