# Entity model not updating /new stored proceedure

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2014-express

A new stored procedure is not imported to the data model when Updating from Database. I have tested updating a table and that works fine.

It has worked fine in the past, the only difference is that I have updated from SQLExpress 2012 to SQLExpress 2014. Since then I have the problem. There are no errors reported after the update. Any help please will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error when editing a Function Import, File not Found.

The following link gave me the answer.

[Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0 not found by visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)