# SQL Server 2016: Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.sdk.sfc=11.0.0.0,''''

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, sql-server-2016

I just installed SQL Server 2016 on my Windows 10 laptop and I am using VS2013 trying to add a connection in server explorer and I am receiving error 'You can not load file or assembly Microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc=11.0.0.0,Culture......'

I did have SQL Server 2008 and SQL server 2014 management studio on my machine which I uninstalled before installing 2016.

I've downloaded and installed SQLSysClrTypes.msi and SharedManagementObjects.msi for 2016 but with no luck.

Any assistance is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The link is [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)

Section description:

Problem: (Sql server 2012) This issue happens when assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0 not found by visual studio.

Solution: just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580 and download:

ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X64 OS or
ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.