# Deploying SSIS Package - 'Failed to load Assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a fresh install of SQL Server 2016 Developer with SSIS, on a clean install of Windows 10

When I try to deploy an SSIS package (developed on the same machine), when I come to select the destination server, I instantly get an error;

> Failed to load assembly
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum

Selecting 'details' doesn't seem to add much

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum, Cluture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx

I've tried doing a repair on the install, to no avail. I've also tried referring to it as both the proper computer name, and localhost, but gives the same error

It's not my first time setting up SQLS & SSIS, but don't recall having any such issues before. The catalog has been created, but wonder if I've missed something out.

Comment: Refer this may help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Comment: Thanks - followed the steps outlined, and installed the SharedManagementObjects and CLR Types for both SQLS2014 & 2016, but hasn't altered the behaviour I'm experiencing.

Comment: This tool has an awful tendency to just stop functioning out of the blue like this. Right now mine has exactly the same error and rather than risk breaking it more I just deploy from SSMS instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are the steps I took to resolve the issue (eventually!)

- I uninstalled all programs relating to Sql Server Data Tools (inc Management Studio, SharedManagementObjects) and anything related to Visual Studio, leaving pretty much just the core database engine and SSIS.
- I performed a 'repair' on what was left of my SQLS installation, mainly to restore anything I'd removed that I shouldn't have
- I then re-downloaded & installed Sql Server Data Tools & Management Studio

Everything now seems to be working as it should.

Comment: For this flaky unreliable tool, sometimes it's the only solution

Answer (score 2):

This bug in some versions of VS data tools can be avoided by running the deployment wizard directly instead of opening it via visual studio.

Locate ISDeploymentWizard.exe for correct version of SQL server, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
```

Double click to run the exe then select your .ispac project file, e.g.

```
C:\SSISProject\bin\Development\SSISPackage.ispac
```

The deployment wizard should now complete without error.

Comment: You can also just use this wizard straight from SSMS by right clicking on a project folder

Comment: Further to @Nick.McDermaid's comment, there is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017#SSMS) on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I performed a repair from the data tools setup menu, and this seems to have solved it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my VS2017 by [downloading SQL Server data tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer) and just chose to install SSIS option.

tried repairing VS2017 installation, that did not work.
Tried VS2019, that did not work.