# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc version=11.0.0.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I am using Database first approach of Entity framework. When I create new connection in "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" then after adding server name and database name, then it shows me this error -

```
Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdkc.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKey Toekn = 89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Found many links on Google and tried but it doesn't solve my issue.

[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)

Tried this
SharedManagementObjects.msi (64 Bit) (Install proper and restart VS and same error occurs again)
PowerShellTools.msi

**Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2, 64 Bit Operating System**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note: x86 or x64 depending on OS Structure**

**Step 1:** Visit the below url and then click on Download option. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580

**Step 2:** select the file name:ENU\ x64 \SQLSysClrTypes.msi and then click on Next. This will shown an option to run this msi file. Please run this msi file and finish the installation.

**Step 3:** Again visit the above link and click on Download option. this time you need to select the file name:ENU\ x64 \SharedManagementObjects.msi and then click on Next. This will shown an option to run this msi file. Please run this msi file and finish the installation.

**Step 4:** Once above 2 files are downloaded and installed. Close the Visual Studio and reopen it. Now you should be able to create the database through server explorer without any errors.

Comment: It's not a solution, if you're running CI on a large pool of build agents, I can't and I don't have permission to update each every build agent with SSDT libraries. What is so special about these SSDT dlls, why can't they just work with nuget like everything else?

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted in this thread as well as other similar threads only apply to SQL Server 2008, 2012 and 2014, but not to SQL Server 2016

I installed ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

I also installed the SQLSysClrTypes.msi, but to no avail.

Finally, I did the following:

1) I ran the SQL Server 2016 setup,

2) I chose to install SSDT from there,  [image: SSDT Selection]

3) Installed all of the things there: analysis, integration, reporting etc

That's it, no more errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used VS 2013 with a database project and Sql server 2016 on my Pc and Sql server 2017(on a remote server). At first, when I created DB, I did not have a problem. But later when I tried to publish the changes I got a similar error. I verified the changes (updates, changes of permissions, ..) on my PC and the sql server and the only thing that changed was DB size.
It helped install VS 2017.