# Error when attempting to create a new Query in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Every Time I attempt to create a New query in Visual Studio 2015 through the SQL Server Object Explorer I receive the following error;

> "could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Controls',
>   version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I've searched for similar problems and as for solutions they've recommended downloading edxtra files or reinstalling, both of which I have done.

At a loss as to what to do as searching for this specific problem only brings up similar names no exact ones.

Any help is appreciated, I'm new to this.

Comment: The question is already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905068/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version. But it is for the 'version=11.0.0.0'. But you can give a try to the solution given over there. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks! The second suggestion worked, just annoyed I couldn't have found this before asking. Appreciate the help.