# SQL Server 2017: Feature Pack Missing File

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I use Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft SQL Server 2017 for a ASP.NET MVC project.

I get an error when I try to connect to the database:

> Could not load file or assembly. 'microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc version=12.0.0.0. Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.

I tried the solution on this link:
[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1?newreg=a71fa6f75dab4efcb8211817a2cc92c2)

I would try the solution for version 2017:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992

But there is no data (`SharedManagementObjects.msi`) for Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack.

Comment: I'm still waiting for help.

Comment: I am also searching. Did you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with SQL Server 2017, Shared Management Objects (SMO) are distributed as the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects NuGet package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: How can I obtain the .dll's needed to run an application that uses this library?

Comment: Just search it via NuGet: Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects