# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer Management.sdk.stc version=12.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2017

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community with SQL Server 2017 Express.

When I try to view my database tables I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer Management.sdk.stc version=12.0.0.0

I have manually installed LocalDb and Management Objects to no avail and this is the only advice I've been able to source.

What I don't understand is why I am getting an error message about management objects when I have installed them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)?

Comment: `'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'` is from the SQL Server 2014 SDK. Sounds like you have a broken installation somewhere. What happens if you use NuGet Package Manager to install the correct version for SQL Server 2017 (version 14) directly into your solution?