# could not load file or assembly microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc version=11.0.0.0 culture=neutral publickeytoken

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2017

I have installed SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio 2013. 
I'm trying to create an Entry data model but it showing me this error

```
"Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc version=11.0.0.0 culture=neutral publickeytoken".
```

also, I installed "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems known issue, as you mentioned you have already installed **Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992.

I would suggest installing **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013** :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Close Visual Studio in installation & open after installation. In most cases restart is not required if Visual Studio & it's dependencies are not open when installation done.

Although this is old question with old version of VS & SQL but interesting read:
[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1)