# SSMS add-in warning

Tags: c#, sql-server, add-in, ssms

I have this add-in for the sql server 2012 following everything the author mentioned but still stuck at this not really an error but not able to figure how to get past this

[How to remove "Server name" items from history of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059105/how-to-remove-server-name-items-from-history-of-sql-server-management-studio)

went thru the above question but not able to figure if this is anyway related ( i think not)

i am following everything the author mentioned here
http://tsqltidy.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-write-sql-server-management_17.html
how to get rid of this? (the error message)
[image]

This the settings in my project properties
[image: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe" is what in the Start external program]

Comment: Looks like the command line argument `/resetaddin SSMSAddinDenali.Connect` isn't supported. The article was written for a CTP. Lots of things can change from those to release. Do you need that argument? Does it work if you remove that entirely?

Comment: WOW that is as far as i went!!.. tks so much

Comment: I have written an article about how to write add-in for SSMS 2012 and included working sample c# project. It is based on release version of SSMS 2012. Article is located [here](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Home/create-own-ssms-2012-add-in-sample-code-with-download), direct project download is [here](http://www.ssmsboost.com/samples/sample-ssms-2012-add-in.zip). Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is for the RC version not the final version right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and after reading [this article](http://satheeq.blogspot.ro/2013/01/how-to-write-sql-server-management.html) I found out that the solution is to simply remove the `/resetaddin ...` parameter.

After doing this it worked fine for me.

Comment: ya tks man.. but i am kind of moved out from Database line.. anyway my past employer didnot encourage me. :(... tks for the direction

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the SSMS 2012 project on Codeproject, but I've been offline a while.

There was a breaking change between the RC and final version, the location of the Addin file has now moved.  I've updated my website/doc to reflect this.  it should be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\AddIns`

Comment: +1 your blog entries about making SSMS add-ins are priceless.