# Removing entries in SQL Server Management Studio database list?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm not sure if this is dev or DBA, but...

When I connect to a database in SQL Server Management Studio, I have a combo with about a dozen entries in it. Half of these are older entries that have moved to new servers. Is there any way to remove these "dead" entries? I can't find anything in the dialog that does this.

Comment: Are you asking about [SQL Admin](http://sqladmin.sourceforge.net/) here? Normally, when using an application, a database will only be displayed if it exists. That suggests those databases haven't been dropped.

Comment: Sorry, SQL SMS. I'll change the title.

Comment: What list do you mean? In the connection window? You can just scroll down to the one you want to delete and hit the delete button.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1059105/4003419)?