# How to remove a database entry, that no longer exists from a SQL Server login drop down list

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v14, and I want to remove items from the login drop down screen, the items refer to databases and login details that don't exist anymore.

I've had a look around and can't see anything specific to my needs.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently im using SQL Server Management Studio 15 (v18) and if you delete UserSettings.xml file in path  C:\Users\%YourUsername%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\%YourVersion% , then your login drop down items are deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to edit the xml file directly ?

Comment: Yes, I updated [my answer over on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996072/61305). While deleting the `UserSettings.xml` file "works" - it removes _every_ connection and other preferences as well.